# maximize a function with recursion c++

Tags: c++, function, recursion, maximization

I am trying to maximize this function in c++:

[image]

I have put this in the function:

```
int F(int n , int T ){

  if( T >= 0  &&  n == 0){

      return 0;

  }else if( T < 0){

      return INT_MIN;

  } else if(T >= 0  &&  n > 0){

      for(int i = 0 ; i <= m[n-1] ; i++){

       ganancia = max(i * v[n-1] + F(n-1,T-i*t[n-1]),ganancia );

      }

  }

}
```

but when I put on n 3 , T 8, t {1, 2, 2}, v {12, 15, 30} and finally on m{3, 3, 2} my program return 2, when it had to return 99.

Comment: In the picture there is an error, the h that is in the first comparison is a T. Sorry.

Comment: The second 'else if' does not return a value?

Comment: It had to return the smallest value on integers.

Comment: Fine, but where is the return statement in your code?

Comment: There are 2 returns, one for the base case, when return 0, and another for the error case, that return INT_MIN.

Comment: Ohh, you are saying that the assignment in the loop, should be a return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three branches in the function, but only two return values. If you fail to return a value you will have *undefined behavior*. You need to return a value from all branches.

Comment: You mean, that I have to return something in the loop?

Comment: @QuicoLlinaresLlorens Not *in* the loop, but afterwards.

Comment: I have put a return after the loop, but the program now shows 81, instead of 13.

Comment: @QuicoLlinaresLlorens And you return a *value*, not just an empty `return` statement? Then you should step through the code in a debugger to help you find the problem. Also note that `int` is a signed type, so you need to think about what happens when `n` is less than zero, a case you don't handle now.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have my code like this:

```
int F(int n , int T ){

  if( T >= 0  &&  n == 0){

      return 0;

  }else if( T < 0){

      return INT_MIN;

  } else if(T >= 0  &&  n > 0){

      for(int i = 0 ; i <= m[n-1]-1 ; i++){

       return (max(i * v[n-1] + F(n-1,T-i*t[n-1]),(i+1) * v[n-1] + F(n-1,T- (i+1)*t[n-1]) ));

      }

  }

}
```

And now it is showing my program 12 instead of 13, at least I have left that 2 value. Thanks!